# Deciding the menu's action dynamically

Tags: android

I add menu's in my application dynamically depending on the values i get from the back-end in the onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu). Now i would want to decide the action that is to be performed for the menu added dynamically (as i do not know the action to be performed beforehand) depending on certain values that came associated with the menu from the back-end. How do i achieve this. Kindly provide me some ideas on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please be more precise about what your problem is

Comment: I would want to associate certain values to the menu that is added to an activity, which i can use in the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) and decide what action needs to be performed depending on the associated values.

Comment: like barmaley said... this is easy and well documented... there shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what i wanted. I put the values associated to the menu as a part of the MenuItems intent. In the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) i get the intent from the MenuItem retrieve the values from it and perform the action required. The code is as below:

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ApplicationManager.getInstance().resetCounter();
    menu.removeGroup(1);
    Vector listOfMenuToBeAdded=Service.getInstance().getMenuList();
    Enumeration<com.data.Menu> menuEnumeration = listOfMenuToBeAdded.elements();
    while (menuEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        com.data.Menu levelOptions = (com.pravaa.mobile.dashboard.data.Menu) menuEnumeration
                .nextElement();
        MenuItem levelMenuItem = menu.add(1, 100, Menu.NONE,
                levelOptions.getCaption());
        LevelOptionIntent levelOptionIntent = new LevelOptionIntent();
        levelOptionIntent.setAppCode(levelOptions.getAppCode());
        levelOptionIntent.setDashboardNumber(levelOptions.getNumber());
        levelOptionIntent.setUniqueRecordId(levelOptions
                    .getUniqueRecordId());
        levelOptionIntent.setLevelNumber(levelOptions.getLevelNo());    
        levelMenuItem.setIntent(levelOptionIntent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Once a menu item is clicked on perform the action according to the values set in the intent.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 100:
        LevelOptionIntent levelOptionIntent = (LevelOptionIntent) item
                .getIntent();
        //Perform what you would want to based on the values set in the intent.
        if (levelOptionIntent.getAppCode().equals(A)) {
        // Start activity A
        }elseif (levelOptionIntent.getAppCode().equals(B)) {
        // Start activity B
        }else if (levelOptionIntent.getAppCode().equals(C)) {
        // Start activity C
        }

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The LevelOptionsIntent class is as below:

```
public class LevelOptionIntent extends Intent {
private int dashboardNumber;
private String appCode;
private String uniqueRecordId;
private int levelNumber;

public LevelOptionIntent() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public int getDashboardNumber() {
    return dashboardNumber;
}
public void setDashboardNumber(int dashboardNumber) {
    this.dashboardNumber = dashboardNumber;
}
public String getAppCode() {
    return appCode;
}
public void setAppCode(String appCode) {
    this.appCode = appCode;
}
public String getUniqueRecordId() {
    return uniqueRecordId;
}
public void setUniqueRecordId(String uniqueRecordId) {
    this.uniqueRecordId = uniqueRecordId;
}
public int getLevelNumber() {
    return levelNumber;
}
public void setLevelNumber(int levelNumber) {
    this.levelNumber = levelNumber;
}}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it though.Can someone throw some light on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the exact problem as yours. Would it be possible to share your code on how you achieved this through MenuItem Intents? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi lini sax, Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Look into `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Basically you need to overwrite them in your `Activity` and handle menus there. You can either remove or add menus in these overwridden methods.

Whole procedure is well-documented and [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: Hi,I am sorry i guess am still not being clear. My problem is i do not know what would be the action that is to be performed when the menu is clicked. The menu that comes to me from the server will decide the action to be performed. For example for a particular activity the server will send me 2 Menus A and B. With A the server will also give me an id of the record that is to be viewed when the user clicks on A and similarly with B. How do i decide the action that is to be performed during runtime as i do not know the action before hand.Sorry for not being clear earlier. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the **option menu**, then this guide should help you: [Changing the Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu).

It shows how you can dynamically add and remove items from the menu right before it is shown to the user using the [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) method, which passes you the menu. You can then add or remove items from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play around with [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29). Here is good [example](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/dynamically-change-options-menu-items-in-android/) how to do that.